# Question about a sequence of iid random variables and the Uniform distribution

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

I will first enuntiate the question and then explain what I'm not understanding.

Suppose $ X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n $ iid with common distribution $ U(0,\theta)$.  Define $M$ as follows:

$ M : =\max\{ X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n \} $

Evaluate :  $\Pr\left( M\leq \frac{\theta }{2} \right ) $

So, i have $ n $ random variables that are independent and identically distributed; I have a another random variable that will yield the maximum value of the mentioned sequence of random variables and then i have to evaluate the probability that this random variable is 'bounded' by $\theta$ divided by two. I understand all this informations separately, but i don't know how to connect them. How in the world, the fact that I know that they are iid and have a uniform distribution with a parameter $ a = 0 $ and $ b = \theta $ will help me finding out the probability of $M$? How even would I know what's the maximum value of the sequence? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The probability that $M\leq \theta/2$ is the same as the probability that all $X_i$s are less than $\theta/2$.

Comment: Also note that if you normalize this to $\theta=1$, it does not affect your answer.

Comment: Sorry but the **maximum** does not do what you say.

Comment: Woops, thank you for catching that. Fixed.

Comment: With that in mind can I affirm that $ Pr\left ( X_{1} ,  X_{2}... X_{n} \leq \frac{\theta }{2} \right ) $ = $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\theta }{2}}\frac{1}{\theta - 0} = 1 $ ?

Comment: No. That does not make much sense. Surely this event must have some positive probability associated with it... $(0,\theta/2)$ is a "big" interval, and there's only finitely many variables. What's the probability of one variable being $\leq \theta/2$?

Comment: @par Since $ \frac{\theta}{2} $ is half the size from $ 0 $ to $ \theta $ i would say 0,5. Values bigger than this would make up the remaining 0,5. Is this correct?

Comment: @matt_zarro : $\Pr(X_1\le\theta/2\ \&\ X_2\le\theta/2\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n\le\theta/2)$ $=\Pr(X_1\le\theta/2)\cdot\Pr(X_2\le\theta/2)\cdots\Pr(X_n\le\theta/)$ $=(\theta/2)(\theta/2)\cdots(\theta/2)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Wow, how didn't i see that!! Thanks Michael

Comment: @MichaelHardy On a second thought, by definition $  F (x) = P(X \leqslant  x)  = \frac{1}{b - a} (x - a) =  \frac{x - a}{b - a}  $ which in this case would lead to $ \frac{\frac{\theta}{2} - 0}{{\theta} - 0} = \frac{1}{2} $. How did you got $ \frac{\theta}{2} $ ?

Comment: @par Any ideas how Michael got that $ \theta/2 $?

Comment: Should be $(1/2)^n$. Probably a typo.

Comment: Sorry: It should have been $1/2$ rather than $\theta/2$, so the product is $1/2^n$. ${}\qquad{}$